# RecursiveAll at the CAML query view scope behaves differently with different SharePoint location

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, caml

I am trying to fetch the files from a SharePoint document library using the CAML query. The files may be present at the document library folder or it's sub-folders. I am able to get the list of files that are present at one SharePoint document library(URL A) folder or it's sub-folders using the `RecursiveAll` scope at the view.

But the same CAML query is not working as expected at the another document library(URL B),which is not having any sub-folders.It's having only files(not any folders) at the SharePoint document library. We could see an "internal server error" as a result.

Is there any SharePoint configuration that got missed to make the `RecursiveAll` functionality behave differently at the document library(URL B)?

Comment: What have you written so far to look up files folders recursively?

Comment: No such configuration based on knowledge, you would check uls log(on-premise) for detailed error information for troubleshooting. C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\LOGS